# ActiveSheet.Copy

Tags: excel, vba

My company has had a Macro that has been running without change for the past two years. With the new Microsoft updates the code has been failing. The Macro has been designed to upload data from another document, re-arrange it, and then send it to a Sample Manager. The following code creates a run-time error '1004' Copy method of Worksheet class failed. When I hit debug ActiveSheet.Copy is highlighted. If anyone has any suggestions, it would help. The code is:

```vb
Sub ExportToLims()
    
    Dim fname As String
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    fname = "X:\LIMS Integration Manager\Entech7200\Input\" & ActiveSheet.Name & "-" & Format(Now(), "mmddyy-hhmm") & ".csv"
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox ("Injection Report Exported to LIMS IM")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the code being executed?

Comment: If `ActiveSheet` is failing, then perhaps the macro is being used in a different setting or context than it was previously. The macro relies on `ActiveSheet` being correctly selected by the user prior to running the macro. When you run the macro, what is the currently active workbook and active sheet?

Comment: There is a macro used before the one above that pulls specific data from a multiple excel files and displays that information in a new spreadsheet. That new spreadsheet is the active sheet. The macro that creates this new sheet works great and display the new data every time. When the final macro is activated, the code above, copy fails to work on the current sheet being viewed.

Comment: If you know the worksheet you want to copy and the workbook it's in you shouldn't use `ActiveSheet`. You might think that refers to the correct sheet in the correct workbook but Excel VBA might see things differently. Try explicitly referencing the worksheet you want to copy.

Comment: I ended up allowing the marcro recorder creating new code. The following works:  Sub Exporttolims()
'
' Exporttolims2 Macro
' Send data to IM
'

'
    ChDir "X:\LIMS Integration Manager\Entech7200\Input"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _
        "X:\LIMS Integration Manager\Entech7200\Input\" & ActiveSheet.Name & "-" & Format(Now(), "mmddyy-hhmm") & ".csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        
        MsgBox ("Injection Report Exported to LIMS IM")
End Sub